# Is it possible to loop through array of specific host and configuration

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have a play that will loop through an array of hosts with a specific host variable configured/defined.

For example, this is my inventory file

```yaml
controlplanes:
  hosts:
    host1.example.com:
workers:
  hosts:
    host2.example.com:
      longhorn:
        storage: true
    host3.example.com:
      longhorn:
        storage: true
```

Basically my goal is to run `kubectl label` command from one host to apply annotations to specific kubernetes nodes, but I only want to have the command run against a specific list of hosts, e.g. hosts that have `longhorn.storage=true`, so in the above example, I should only loop through 2 hosts.

Is this possible? I know I can loop through all hosts, but I can't seem to access variables of any given host, I thought `hostvars[hostname].longhorn.storage` might give me access, but results seem to indicate it's not defined, so I think my approach is incorrect.

```yaml
- name: Loop Test
  hosts: controlplanes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list *longhorn_group* in the first play

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        longhorn_storage: "{{ longhorn.storage|d(false) }}"
    - set_fact:
        longhorn_group: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                            selectattr('value.longhorn_storage')|
                            map(attribute='key') }}"
      run_once: true
```

and use it in the second play

```yaml
- hosts: controlplanes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: longhorn_group
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ longhorn_group }}"
```

gives (abridge)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com] => 
  longhorn_group:
  - host2.example.com
  - host3.example.com

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com] => (item=host2.example.com) => 
  msg: host2.example.com
ok: [host1.example.com] => (item=host3.example.com) => 
  msg: host3.example.com
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        longhorn_storage: "{{ longhorn.storage|d(false) }}"
    - set_fact:
        longhorn_group: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                            selectattr('value.longhorn_storage')|
                            map(attribute='key') }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: controlplanes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: longhorn_group
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ longhorn_group }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspected, but just confirmed, that one can safely call [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) with an existing inventory host and at that time assign the "new" host to groups, as well as add any additional hostvars that you wish

given an inventory of

```ini
[controlplane]
alpha ansible_host=127.0.0.5

[workers]
beta ansible_host=127.0.0.6
charlie ansible_host=127.0.0.7

[workers:vars]
longhorn=true
```

then the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      add_host:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        groups:
        - longer
        have_longhorn: true
      loop: '{{ long_hosts | from_yaml }}'
      vars:
        # this nonsense is because jinja2 does not have list comprehensions
        long_hosts: |
          {% for hn in groups["all"] if 'longhorn' in hostvars[hn] %}
          - {{ hn }}
          {% endfor -%}

- hosts: longer
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ inventory_hostname }} ({{ ansible_host }}) have_long={{ have_longhorn }}
          long={{ longhorn }}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought `hostvars[hostname].longhorn.storage` might give me access, but results seem to indicate it's not defined.

It is defined only for hosts where the var is present in your inventory. For example, it is undefined for your `controlplanes`. So the correct way to call that var is to use the [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) (alias `d`) to make sure you always get a value e.g.:

```yaml
    when: hostvars[hostname].longhorn.storage | d(false) | bool
```

Note as well the use of the [`bool` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/bool_filter.html) to secure the result in case the var has been parsed as a string from the inventory.

Meanwhile, If I understood your requirement correctly, this example is IMO a perfect candidate for a [`constructed` dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html).

Example file structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── dummy_playbook.yml
└── inventories
    └── demo
        ├── 01-hosts.yml
        └── 02-longhorn_group-constructed.yml
```

I modified your initial inventory a bit for the need of this example. This is the content of `inventories/demo/01-hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
controlplanes:
  hosts:
    host1.example.com:
workers:
  hosts:
    host2.example.com:
      longhorn:
        storage: true
    # Example to show it does not break if var isn't defined
    host3.example.com:
    host4.example.com:
      longhorn:
        storage: true
    host5.example.com:
      longhorn:
        storage: false
```

The magic takes place in `inventories/demo/02-longhorn_group-constructed.yml`. We create a dynamic group based on the variable value from the former static inventory file:

```yaml
---
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
strict: False
groups:
  longhorn_storage: longhorn.storage | d(false) | bool
```

We can then quickly test this is working with `dummy_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Run a task from controlplane for each host having longhorn storage
  hosts: controlplanes
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Dummy demo tasks
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - I'm running from {{ inventory_hostname }}
          - I would do something for target {{ item }}
      loop: "{{ groups.longhorn_storage }}"
```

Test playbook result:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ dummy_playbook.yml 

PLAY [Run a task from controlplane for each host having longhorn storage] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Dummy demo tasks] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com] => (item=host2.example.com) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running from host1.example.com",
        "I would do something for target host2.example.com"
    ]
}
ok: [host1.example.com] => (item=host4.example.com) => {
    "msg": [
        "I'm running from host1.example.com",
        "I would do something for target host4.example.com"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1.example.com          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

An other way to check the inventory is parsed as expected is simply to list its content with the command `ansible-inventory -i inventories/demo/ --list` giving:

```json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "host2.example.com": {
                "longhorn": {
                    "storage": true
                }
            },
            "host4.example.com": {
                "longhorn": {
                    "storage": true
                }
            },
            "host5.example.com": {
                "longhorn": {
                    "storage": false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "controlplanes",
            "workers",
            "longhorn_storage"
        ]
    },
    "controlplanes": {
        "hosts": [
            "host1.example.com"
        ]
    },
    "longhorn_storage": {
        "hosts": [
            "host2.example.com",
            "host4.example.com"
        ]
    },
    "workers": {
        "hosts": [
            "host2.example.com",
            "host3.example.com",
            "host4.example.com",
            "host5.example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this helps gives me another option through the use of the `constructed` plugin. I hadn't use this before, so I will definitely give this a check.